# List to LINQ query

Tags: linq

I have a database SP which return result in the form as below.

```
ProductID ProductName Composition 
1          PRod1       pc1
1          PRod1       pc11
2          PRod2       pc2
2          PRod2       pc22
1          Prod1       pc111
```

As this is being returned in as a list and I do have a ViewModel which contain 
PVM{productId, productName and List compostionVM } and compsotionVM{productID,Compostion}

I was looking to extract from the above result

```
Result.Select(r =>new PVM{Id = r.Id,Name = r.ProductName,                                         compsotionVM ).ToList()}).ToList();
```

i.e.   product Id ,Prouct Name and List of all compostion to bind to View.
Any help or suggestion will be of gr8 help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below:

```
result.GroupBy(item => new{item.ProductID, item.ProductName})
                     .Select(group => 
                         new PVM
                             {
                                 ProductID = group.Key.ProductID, 
                                 ProductName= group.Key.ProductName, 
                                 Compositions = 
                                    group
                                    .Select(g=>
                                        new CompositionVM
                                        {
                                            ProductID = g.ProductID, 
                                            Composition = g.Composition
                                        })
                                        .ToList()
                             });
```

As you want to group the Product with same name(x) and Id(y) together by combine the Composition(z) column.

So the idea here is group by the 2 group conditions (x and y) in the main query, then for each item in the query would be a combination of items in the same group which allows you to do a subquery like

```
group
.Select(g=>
  new CompositionVM
  {
      ProductID = g.ProductID, 
      Composition = g.Composition
  })
  .ToList()
```

Comment: Zhang ,Thanks and appreciate your response and time will implement and see.